# Synchronize a SVN server to my SVN server. I don't have access to modify the 1st server

Tags: svn, version-control, synchronization

I am working with a svn server from time to time, I update my local version of the code and then I checkin the changes to my svn server, this is for safety reasons I don't want to keep the code only on my machine in case I lose my machine.

I don't have access to the svn server where I am getting code from, so I cannot make any modifications on that.

How can I automate the process to regularly(maybe scheduled) make updates from the svn server to my svn server?
I guess the only way is to have my server a scheduled task to get the code from that svn server? What I would like is to also send an email when the code was updated on my server.

On the long-term, can you see any issues with that?

Thanks!

Comment: By "don't have access", do you mean you don't have administrative access? Or do you mean that you can't commit to the "central" svn server?  If you are allowed to commit to the central server, but simply don't have administrative access, you may want to look into creating a "feature branch" on the central server (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.html) to solve your problem, rather than maintaining your own copy of the entire repository.

Comment: yes, I don't have access to both the server and the svn server. I am able to commit there. I don't think you understood my problem. I need to duplicate svn server on another server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version  of answer

Use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) on the side of your repo ([another version is manual](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt) or [third version is HowTo](http://blog.notreally.org/2006/11/30/setting-up-a-subversion-mirror-repository-using-svnsync/))

> send an email when the code was updated on my server

It's hand-made post-commit hook or [svn-notify](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SVN-Notify/)|[Subversion  Notify](http://subversionnotify.com/default.aspx)

Comment: thanks! any known issues with svnsync? I really need something reliable.

Comment: for example, wouldn't be much safer if I would just schedule the command 'svn update' on my server? since i never modify the code on the local repository from the server, the updates should always run without problems

Comment: `svn up` updates working copy linked to original repo, *not repository*. No, I heard nothing about svnsync troubles

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you want to synchronize SVN repositories.

[SVK](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage) is the tool for [the job](http://developer.mindtouch.com/User%3aPeteE/Synchronizing_SVN_Repositories_With_Svk)